# Is There Command on CMD to list all deployments lambdas(Functions) on AWS by the serverless framework?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless

I have been deploying Lambdas to AWS by Serverless framework I need a command to list all lambdas information by **Command Prompt**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CLI to return a list of Lambda functions. For details, see here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/list-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

`sls info` should do it. It will then list all the data that normally gets shown at the end of a deployment. Of course, you can just look in the serverless.yml file to see what funcitons you have configured.